# How correctly center a table into its div container?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I am not so into HTML and CSS and I have some problem to put a table at the center of its container. So I have the following situation:

```
<!-- SEDE LEGALE: -->
<div id="sedeLegaleTab">
    <table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">
        <thead class="opening active">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow_down.gif"/>
                    Sede Legale
                </th>
             </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="expanded" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="sedeLegaleContent" class="accordion-pane-content">
                        <table class="standard-table-cls" style="width: 90%;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Ragione Sociale</td>
                                    <td colspan=5>
                                        <input type="TEXT" name="ragsoc" size=60 maxlength=100 <%=master?"":"readonly"%>
                                               class="testosmallUpper" value="<%= ragioneSociale %>" onblur="MakeItUpper(event,this)">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                ..............................................
                                ..............................................
                                ..............................................
                                OTHER TR
                                ..............................................
                                ..............................................
                                ..............................................
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I know that it is a pretty orrible old table layout but it is a very old legacy application and I have to work on it.

So this is a screenshot of what it is rendered by the content of this table (that is into the previous code):

```
<table class="standard-table-cls" style="width: 90%;">
```

[image]

Now, as you can see, this table is into a div having **id="sedeLegaleContent"** and it have setted **style="width: 90%;"**

So I need to center it inside its container (the div having **id="sedeLegaleContent"**)

What can I try to do it?

I can do it adding to this div the **align="center"** attribute, in this way:

```
<div id="sedeLegaleContent" class="accordion-pane-content" align="center">
```

But can I do it in some better way using the CSS? Or is it a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4rv95L9m/)**

CSS:

```
table{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```